# Magento 2: Show Tax amount in Product View

Tags: magento2.2, magento-2.2.5

I'm trying to show the Tax Amount in Product View. I've set the TAX to including TAX in Calculation Setting.

[image: Calculation Setting]

I wanna show the Tax amount like this.
[image]

and I've Create the Tax Rate & Tax Rule.

I try to use this code in my Block, but I got nothing.

```
public function getPriceInclAndExclTax(int $productId): array
{
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

    if ($taxAttribute = $product->getCustomAttribute('tax_class_id')) {
        // First get base price (=price excluding tax)
        $productRateId = $taxAttribute->getValue();
        $rate = $this->taxCalculation->getCalculatedRate($productRateId);

        if ((int) $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                'tax/calculation/price_includes_tax',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE) === 1
        ) {
            // Product price in catalog is including tax.
            $priceExcludingTax = $product->getPrice() / (1 + ($rate / 100));
        } else {
            // Product price in catalog is excluding tax.
            $priceExcludingTax = $product->getPrice();
        }

        $priceIncludingTax = $priceExcludingTax + ($priceExcludingTax * ($rate / 100));

        return [
            'incl' => $priceIncludingTax,
            'excl' => $priceExcludingTax
        ];
    }

    throw new LocalizedException(__('Tax Attribute not found'));
}
```

I try to print getPriceInclAndExclTax()

```
Array ( [incl] => 0 [excl] => 0 )
```

Comment: you have the possibility to show the tax amount on Summary area, if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, I wanna show the tax amount after final prices. https://prnt.sc/kgichm